# Spawning Player at certain Point in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a small 2d click'n'point in Unity, and what I want to do is: I want to move towards the door and when my Player steps on a game Object with an attached SceneSwitcher Script he shall go through the door, into another scene. That works fine so far. Now I don't want him to appear in the middle of the room, but on the door, where he entered the room.

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using PixelCrushers.DialogueSystem;

public class ScenSwitcher : MonoBehaviour {

 public string SceneName = "";

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
     SwitchScene();
 }

 void SwitchScene(){
     LevelManager levelManager = DialogueManager.Instance.GetComponent<LevelManager>();
     levelManager.LoadLevel (SceneName);
     changePosition ();
     Debug.Log ("Scene Wechseln nach: " + SceneName);
 }
 void changePosition(){
     GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
     player.transform.position = new Vector3(12,12,0);
 }

}
```

That is my code, it does change Scenes, but not change the position. I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ChangePosition() method you are passing hardcoded values to player position and it will assume always (12,12,0) on your scene space.

You need to define a spawn manager where you will get dynamically witch spawn point in your scene you want to use.

**edited:**

1: Try to create a singleton GameManager ( you can find singleton pattern examples [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) ) (IMPORTANT: Add [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) on your GameManager Awake).

2: In your GameManager define a Vector3 NextPosition property or something like this.

3: Declare a public Vector3 Destination on your "teleport" script to set it per teleport on inspector/editor.

4: Before this line `levelManager.LoadLevel (SceneName)` of code set GameManager.NextPosition = this.Destination;

5: If you are not persisting your character between scenes just call on one of hes behaviours Awake() or, if he persists create a method void [OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html) and chage players position setting GameManager.NextPosition ( wisely testing if it is valid for the [current level](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-loadedLevel.html) before ;) ).

I cant try or do better coding now because I don't have access to unity editor so I hope it helps at last start a good research to solve your problem =/.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I would've even been fine with the (12,12,0), but it doesn't change the position it all :/

Comment: edited my answer with another approach once Christian pointed an error on last one.

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do and it still leaves room for multiple implementations for you to practice with. Without actually doing it for you, I would mark this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the loadLevel function destroys the current script so changePosition does not get executed? I could be wrong.

Even if it is getting executed, there is a good chance it is executed before the level load and the properties for the next scene override where it got moved to.

I forget the exact syntax but look into getting GameObjects to not be destroyed on scene change.

**EDIT**

[Object.DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Comment: You are right Christian, my mistake. Think DontDestroyOnLoad directly on this kind of component is not the best solution.

Comment: In which case, use a small holder object that stores the spawn position that is not destroyed on load. And in that object, onload, reposition the player.

Comment: this is what I means when told about a spawn manager, this kind of system is huge discussed in many threads, and could be made ion many different ways. Ozymandias will need to do some research but I'll try to edit my answer for a better and not bugged solution.